# How to write in the same file C++

Tags: c++, string, file

I need to delete all the occurencies of a string in a file.
I receive the text as a string and erase every occurencies.
After I deleted all the occurencies i don't know how to save the string back to the file.

I've tried to close the file and wit ofstream to write in it but it didn't work.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main () {
    std::string file_contents = "";
    std::ifstream myfile ("text.txt");

    char ch;

    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        // READ FILE CONTENTS AS STRING
        while ( myfile >> std::noskipws >> ch)
        {
            file_contents += ch;
        }

        // DISPLAY STRING
        std::cout << file_contents << '\n';

        // GET WORD TO BE DELETED
        std::string word;
        std::cout << "Please enter word to be deleted: ";
        std::cin >> word;

        std::string::size_type found;

        std::string new_text;
        //DELETE WORD FROM STRING
        bool ok=0;
        do{
        found = file_contents.find(word);
        ok=1;
        if (found!=std::string::npos)
        {
            std::cout << word << " found at: " << found << '\n';
            file_contents.erase(found, word.length());
            std::cout << file_contents << '\n';

        }
        else
            ok==0;
            new_text=file_contents;
        }while(ok==1);



        myfile.close();
    }

    else std::cout << "Unable to open file";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ifstream` is input file stream, it can't put things in the file. Why don't you close ifstream, remove the word from retrieved content and then open the same file using `ofstream` and write all the content?

Comment: Please show a [mre], you say you tried to use an `ofstream` but it didn't work, in what way didn't it work? Where is the code for this?

Comment: I've tried but it didn't work. The file remained the  same

Comment: Side note: Please use `true` or `false` for `bool` variables.

Comment: @user9888273 I have added an answer that works.

Comment: one way would be to open two files, one to read from the other to write to, then read line by line and remove the string you want to erase and write it back to the new file. Once done delete original and rename new file to the original name.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so you must close `ifstream` instance before proceeding to write to the file again.

After closing the file, modify the content and then open the same file for write using `ofstream` and simply write the content.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main() {
  std::string file_contents = "";
  std::ifstream myfile("text.txt");

  char ch;

  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    // READ FILE CONTENTS AS STRING
    while (myfile >> std::noskipws >> ch)
    {
      file_contents += ch;
    }
    myfile.close();
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Unable to open file";
    return -1; // no need to continue if can't read it
  }

  // DISPLAY STRING
  std::cout << file_contents << '\n';

  // GET WORD TO BE DELETED
  std::string word;
  std::cout << "Please enter word to be deleted: ";
  std::cin >> word;

  //DELETE WORD FROM STRING
  size_t found;
  while ((found = file_contents.find(word)) != file_contents.npos)
  {
    std::cout << word << " found at: " << found << '\n';
    file_contents.erase(found, word.length());
    std::cout << file_contents << '\n';
  }

  // this will open in text mode and will replace all existing content
  std::ofstream out("text.txt"); 
  if (out.is_open()) {
    out << file_contents;
    out.close();
  }
  else {
    std::cout << "Unable to open file for writing.\n";
    return -2; // for failure to open for write
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Note: the loop you had went infinitely when I tried to execute it, I had to change it to the code shown above. Also, `new_text` is completely unnecessary, why have it?

Answer (score 0):

The simpliest way is first to open as input stream. When finish open as output stream to write. It is not the only way you can do that.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main ()
{
    std::string file_contents = "";
    {
        std::ifstream myfile ("text.txt");

        if (! myfile.is_open()) 
        {
            else std::cout << "Unable to open file";
            return 1;
        }

        // READ FILE CONTENTS AS STRING
        char ch;
        while ( myfile >> std::noskipws >> ch) file_contents += ch;
        myfile.close();
    }


    {
        std::string word;
        std::cin >> word; // GET WORD TO BE DELETED
        std::string::size_type found;
        while((found = file_contents.find(word))!=std::string::npos)
            file_contents.erase(found, word.length());

        std::ofstream myfile ("text.txt");
        myfile << file_contents<< std::flush;
        myfile.close();
    }


    return 0;
}
```